# Android - What is the name of this kind of effect on android?

Tags: java, android

How can I do the same that Shazam and Facebook Messeger do? How can I code something like this button that appears to get sound in shazam?
What is the name of this thing? Notification fab?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you might be talking about are `Widgets`. Check out this link:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/overview

Comment: FLOATING WIDGETS